# Payment Gateway to accept UPI payments in Expo react native app

Tags: react-native, expo, in-app-purchase, payment

I am developing an app for bike renting where i want to get payment from user. the app is in expo react native. I wanted to integrate a payment gateway but razorpay does not support for expo. what is the alternative way to accept the payment using upi for expo project.
Paytm and Razorpay are not supported as i view on Youtube and stackoverflow. suggest any other way to integrate the payment gateway